# Website performance tips?

Tags: performance, htaccess

I'm kind of having some troubles with the loading of [my website](http://greek-night.co.uk).
It sometimes loads fast, then when you refresh it, most of the time, it will just keep trying to load images.  It will keep doing that for a minute or so, and none of the JavaScript will execute.

I have followed most of the tips given by Yahoo, except caching, which I couldn't get working properly.

Does anyone know how to do proper caching of image and JavaScript files using *htaccess*? Most of the code I found online won't work.

Comment: most of the code should work... have you checked the error log of apache?

Comment: No.. where is it located?

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=apache+error+log+location

Comment: It's empty for today..

Comment: How much effort have you exerted with caching? Although this link gives you the full tutorial: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/speed-up-sites-with-htaccess-caching.html. These links may also help you: http://tutorialpedia.org/tutorials/Apache+enable+file+caching+with+htaccess.html & http://www.thecreatology.com/how-to-improve-website-performance-by-image-caching-using-htaccess.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [link](http://www.thecreatology.com/how-to-improve-website-performance-by-image-caching-using-htaccess.html) given by Ann B, has solved all of my problems.